spring security /.well-known/jwks.json custom filter 401 error
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/error/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/oauth2/token").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/.well-known/jwks.json").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
                .addFilterAfter(authorizationFilter, AuthorizationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }


@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("# start authorization");
        String clientSecret = request.getHeader("client_secret");
        String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();

        if (clientSecret == null || !clientService.authenticateClient(clientSecret)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid client secret~!@@@@@@");
            return;
        }

        if (!clientService.hasAccess(clientSecret, requestUri)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access denied to the requested API~");
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

I created a CustomAuthorizationFilter and added the filter to the SecurityFilterChain as described above.
However, when I send a request to the local resource server (http://localhost:8090/.well-known/jwks.json), it should always return a result, but it keeps throwing an error that I have configured:
What could be the cause of this?
{
    "timestamp": "2024-05-21T02:29:57.554+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Invalid client secret~!@@@@@@",
    "path": "/.well-known/jwks.json"
}

I am trying to create an authorization feature using a custom filter that uses the information contained in the token. The goal is to allow the client to access the API URI if they have the appropriate permissions, and return an error if they do not.
